# Teleport entities relatively to the center of a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just wanted to teleport an entity relatively, but the entity is not exactly in the middle of a block.

For example the coordinates are **0.3, 63.0, 0.76** and I teleport the entity relatively using **~1 ~0 ~1**. The resulting coordinated will be **1.3, 63.0, 1.76** but I want the entity to be in the center of the block. So it has to be **1.5, 63.0, 1.5** instead.

Is it possible to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Don't think there is such possible way to do this, simply with static command blocks. (You can't scoreboard either as there is no scoreboard variable for a player's X/Y/Z co-ordinate) | The best I can suggest is (if you know the actual position they're going to be close to, use a plain `/tp @a[1.5,63,1.5,r=1] 1.5 63.0 1.5` command-block, running on a clock, or is triggered after the initial `/tp @a ~1 ~0 ~1`. **Though it'd be a really stupid and inefficient method if the destination is a large region, instead of a single block..**

Comment: Sadly it is a relatively large area. Using this method I had to use 113 command blocks. But at the moment I don't have a better idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, teleport or summon the entity relatively as you're doing at the moment.

There are a few ways to center an entity on a block. Some of the more clunky methods involve teleporting the entity elsewhere, shoving it against the corner and then teleporting it ~0.3 ~ ~0.3, or similar things.

The method I think works best is by using paintings or item frames. When summoned, they're always at the same location in the block:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vlq6Zmp.png]

They're horizontally centered, and -0.469 off on the Z axis. This means that to center yourself, you can teleport to an item frame, and then teleport ~0.469.

So your order of commands should be something like this:

```
Your relative teleport/summon
/execute @e[name=Name] ~ ~ ~ /summon ItemFrame
/execute @e[name=Name] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=ItemFrame,c=1,r=1]
/tp @e[name=Name] ~ ~ ~0.469
/execute @e[name=Name] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[type=ItemFrame,c=1,r=1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Leash Knots like this:

```
/execute @e[name=Name] ~ ~ ~ /summon leash_knot ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Centre}

/tp @e[name=Name] @e[name=Centre,c=1]

/kill @e[name=Centre]
```

(This is for 1.11, for 1.10 or lower use LeashKnot instead of leash_knot)

For 1.13+:

```
/execute as @e[name=Name] at ~ ~ ~ /summon leash_knot ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["Centre"]}

/tp @e[name=Name] @e[tag=Centre,limit=1]

/kill @e[tag=Centre]
```

Answer (score 0):

When summoning relatively to command blocks, like ~ ~5 ~, it will summon it in the middle of the block.

Or, you can use a spawn egg, because when you use a spawn egg to spawn a zombie, the zombie will be in the middle of the block. So you can use execute and summon something at the zombie then kill the zombie.